# iPhone +OpenGL ES: accessing depth texture values using oes_depth_texture

Tags: iphone, shader, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to access a depth texture, that I have created with FBO but I don't know how. I have tried to use texture2D, but I am not sure in which component the values are stored or if these values are split up and stored in more than one component.

The Definition of the texture:

glTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,480,360,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);

Needless to say, that i am new to iPhone and OpenGL ES programming.

Thanks in advance

Lars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i was hasty. The value can be accessed from each component (except the fourth one of course).